# How to align more chessboard with LaTeX using Skak package?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pdftex, skak

I've tried using the align environment, I've tried using minipage but nothing seems to work. This is my code.
Edit : As someone asked I'll try to be more clear, I want the two right-most picture to begin at the same point(just like the two on the left do)

```
\section{London System}

\newgame

\mainline{1.d4 d5} 

\showboard \mainline{2.Nf3 Nc6} \showboard

\mainline{3.Bf4 Nf6} 

\showboard \mainline{4.e3 e6 5.Bd3 Be5 6.Nd2}\showonlywhite \showboard
```

[image: This is the result, as you can see in the second line, the third chessboard is aligned with the first but the fourth isn't with the second]

Comment: you should show a complete example, and you should better describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: off topic: `align` is specific to math display environment from `amsmath`.  I've changed the tag appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your layout, but you can for example use a tabular. As you didn't provide a complete example I used xskak and chessboard here, I know them better ....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak,longtable}

\begin{document}
\section{London System}
\newchessgame

\setchessboard{smallboard,showmover=false,}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.45\textwidth}p{0.45\textwidth}}
\mainline{1.d4 d5}

\chessboard 
&
\mainline{2.Nf3 Nc6} 

\chessboard
\\
\mainline{3.Bf4 Nf6}

\chessboard
&
\mainline{4.e3 e6 5.Bd3 Be5 6.Nd2}

\chessboard[hideblack]
\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]